# anyone knows why this ABRT occurs?

Tags: linux, centos, sudo, abrt

anyone knows what this error is?

> ABRT has detected 1 problem(s). For more info run: abrt-cli list --since

i got this, when i run "sudo su -"

thanks

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Question may be appropriate for [Superuser](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Answer (score 0):

ABRT is the abbreviation for Automatic Bug Reporting Tool. It actually detects on your system crashes in applications written in C/C++ and Python, as well as kernel oopses. To figure out the details you would have to run `abrt-cli list --since` as it suggests.

Answer (score 0):

#systemctl disable initial-setup-text.service

- Root Cause---

The error is coming from the initial-setup package.

Verify  - Reboot machine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).